# What is ${\cal D}(\Omega_0)\otimes{\cal D}(\Omega_1)$?

Tags: tensor-products, distribution-theory, book-recommendation, online-resources

How exactly can I prove that ${\cal D}(\Omega_0)\otimes{\cal D}(\Omega_1)$ equals the linear space $M$ spanned by 'simple fucntions' $\phi\in{\cal D}(\Omega_0\times\Omega_1)$ of the form $\phi(x,y)=\phi_0(x)\phi_1(y)$ for $\phi_i\in{\cal D}(\Omega_i)$?

I mean, it makes intuitively sense to me, but it still seems hard to carry out the proof in detail.  What puzzles me, given bilinear $f:{\cal D}(\Omega_0)\times{\cal D}(\Omega_1)\rightarrow U$, when I try to extend $f$ to a linear function on $M$, how can I make sure that the value of $\chi\in M$ under $f$ does not depend on the decomposition of $\chi$ into 'simple functions'?

Maybe there is some book / online resource where I can look for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good reference on this is Friendlander and Joshi, *[Introduction to the Theory of Distributions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521649714)*. The section on tensor product is at Chapter 4, page 44. The theorem you cited seems to be largely similar to Theorem 4.3.2 in the book, and it is largely a standard $\epsilon-\delta$ type definition style proof. Correct me if I am mistaken as I am not familiar with your notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link.  I'm currently reading through, not entirely sure if it adresses my question exactly, but definitly helpful.